# 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensor

I wanted to extract and apply independently a `Conv2D` layer on the columns of my input tensors, but after adding the code:

```
accelerometer_input = Input(shape=(1400, 3))

for i in range(3):
    out = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:, i:i+1])(accelerometer_input) # Extracting the ith channel
    out = K.expand_dims(out, axis=1)
    out = Conv2D(64, (30, 1), data_format="channels_first")(out)  
    branch_outputs.append(out)
out_put = K.concatenate(branch_outputs)
```

it gives me the error in the title. I think it is due to the `Lambda` layer or the *extraction* which is not differentiable.

But how can I do without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are directly applying a backend function (i.e. `K.expand_dims()`) on a Keras Tensor (i.e. `out`) and therefore the result would be a Tensor (and not a Keras Tensor). Actually, a Keras Tensor is an augmented version of Tensor and have additional attributes (e.g. `_keras_history`) which helps Keras to build the model. Now, to resolve the issue, you just need to put the backend function in a `Lambda` layer to have a Keras Tensor as output:

```
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=1))(out)
```

The same thing applies to using `K.concatenate()`. However in this case, there is a specific layer for it in Keras:

```
from keras.layers import concatenate, Concatenate

# use functional interface
out_put = concatenate(branch_outputs)

# or use layer class
out_put = Concatenate()(branch_outputs)
```

Comment: it was: `out_put = K.concatenate(branch_outputs)`, I removed the `K.`and worked. Your answer helped me understand it, so if you want you can add it to your answer and i'll accept it

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro Oh! I did not even see that line. Yeah, it is wrong as well for the same reason. You need to use the `Concatenate` layer instead. I have updated my answer.